# SAMBA - Cannot access windows shared folders with samba in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: windows, samba, 22.04, shared-folders

I'm new with Samba and need help. I shared folders in windows 7 in workgroup and i can visualize them on windows and ubuntu 22.04 computer but when I try to access one of them only in ubuntu as a registered user (u and pass ok)  I cannot and receive the follow message: "UNABLE TO ACCESS LOCATION - Failed to mount windows share. Invalid Argument."

I already ping server's IP (thats ok) reinstalled samba, smbclient, tried to access from smb:// servers-name, smb://servers-ip, mount a partition in a folder of ubuntu, reinstall CIFS dependecies, re-configured smb.conf.   and changed name of user, computers name, workgroup name and nothing works, the same message, Someone have another ideia?

command I used to mount

```
sudo mount-t cifs -o username=seunome,password=yourpassword//servidor /mnt /MinhaPasta
```

ou

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.13 /mnt/rede-win7 -o user=admin,password=xxxxxx,domain=workgroup,vers=1.0
```

when I put this in terminal `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`
I have a follow log:

Aug  4 kernel: [44203.523336] Malformed UNC in devname
Aug  4 kernel: [44203.523336]
Aug  4 kernel: [44203.523348] CIFS: VFS: Malformed UNC in devname

Comment: You shouldn't be using Windows 7, period. The likely reason you're having problems is the obsolete Windows version still using a deprecated SMB v.1 that's no longer supported by any modern Linux distro or currently supported Windows versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I dont undertood as well. A few days ago the same shared folders was functioning without any error in the same machines. How can I fix this?

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment with an hypotheses. If it working before then the hypotheses might not be correct after all.

Comment: I also perceived that '/var/log/samba' cannot created any file of log.But I dont  know why

Answer (score -2):

I resolved that question unintaling samba again and after i put the command:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

and stayed waiting untill update all and after I installed samba again with:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall samba
```

the shared folders in windows 7 appeared again and when I clicked double click in one of them, it asked me a username and password of windows user and I was able login and access the directory again.